# JsonConverter with Interface

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have an object which comes from the client and get deserialized from the Web Api 2 automatically.

Now I have a problem with one property of my model. This property "CurrentField" is of Type IField and there are 2 different Implementations of this interface.

This is my model (just a dummy)

```
public class MyTest
{
    public IField CurrentField {get;set;}
}

public interface IField{
    string Name {get;set;}
}

public Field1 : IField{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int MyValue {get;set;}
}

public Field2 : IField{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MyStringValue {get;set;}
}
```

I tried to create a custom JsonConverter to find out of what type my object from the client is (Field1 or Field2) but I just don't know how.

My Converter gets called and I can see the object when I call
var obj = JObject.load(reader);

but how can I find out what type it is? I can't do something like

```
if(obj is Field1) ...
```

this is the method where I should check this right?

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
```

Comment: [This SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273730/checking-for-object-type-compatibility-at-runtime) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742276/in-c-how-do-i-check-if-a-type-is-a-subtype-or-the-type-of-an-object) should help you.

Comment: Why not just use [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)?  It's designed for exactly this situation and records the actual .Net type used for the interface in the JSON.

Comment: @dbc: thanks for your quick answer but it still doesn't work even if i add this to my configuration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**How to automatically select a concrete type when deserializing an interface using Json.NET**

The easiest way to solve your problem is to serialize and deserialize your JSON (on both the client and server sides) with [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  If you do, your JSON will include the actual type serialized for an `IFIeld` property, like so:

> ```
> {
>   "CurrentField": {
>     "$type": "MyNamespace.Field2, MyAssembly",
>     "Name": "name",
>     "MyStringValue": "my string value"
>   }
> }
> ```

However, note this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182), [How to configure Json.NET to create a vulnerable web API](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html), and Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh's blackhat paper https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf

If for whatever reason you cannot change what the server outputs, you can create a `JsonConverter` that loads the JSON into a `JObject` and checks to see what fields are actually present, then searches through possible concrete types to find one with the same properties:

```
public class JsonDerivedTypeConverer<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public JsonDerivedTypeConverer() { }

    public JsonDerivedTypeConverer(params Type[] types)
    {
        this.DerivedTypes = types;
    }

    readonly HashSet<Type> derivedTypes = new HashSet<Type>();

    public IEnumerable<Type> DerivedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return derivedTypes.ToArray(); 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            derivedTypes.Clear();
            if (value != null)
                derivedTypes.UnionWith(value);
        }
    }

    JsonObjectContract FindContract(JObject obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<JsonObjectContract> bestContracts = new List<JsonObjectContract>();
        foreach (var type in derivedTypes)
        {
            if (type.IsAbstract)
                continue;
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
            if (contract == null)
                continue;
            if (obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).Any(n => contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(n) == null))
                continue;
            if (bestContracts.Count == 0 || bestContracts[0].Properties.Count > contract.Properties.Count)
            {
                bestContracts.Clear();
                bestContracts.Add(contract);
            }
            else if (contract.Properties.Count == bestContracts[0].Properties.Count)
            {
                bestContracts.Add(contract);
            }
        }
        return bestContracts.Single();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(T);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader); // Throws an exception if the current token is not an object.
        var contract = FindContract(obj, serializer);
        if (contract == null)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("no contract found for " + obj.ToString());
        if (existingValue == null || !contract.UnderlyingType.IsAssignableFrom(existingValue.GetType()))
            existingValue = contract.DefaultCreator();
        using (var sr = obj.CreateReader())
        {
            serializer.Populate(sr, existingValue);
        }
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can apply that as a converter to `IField`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonDerivedTypeConverer<IField>), new object [] { new Type [] { typeof(Field1), typeof(Field2) } })]
public interface IField
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note that this solution is a little fragile.  If the server omits the `MyStringValue` or `MyValue` fields (because they have default value and [`DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm), for example) then the converter won't know which type to create and will throw an exception.  Similarly, if two concrete types implementing `IField` have the same property names, differing only in type, the converter will throw an exception.  Using `TypeNameHandling.Auto` avoids these potential problems.

**Update**

The following version checks to see if the `"$type"` parameter is present, and if `TypeNameHandling != TypeNameHandling.None`, falls back on default serialization.  It has to do a couple of tricks to prevent infinite recursion when falling back:

```
public class JsonDerivedTypeConverer<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public JsonDerivedTypeConverer() { }

    public JsonDerivedTypeConverer(params Type[] types)
    {
        this.DerivedTypes = types;
    }

    readonly HashSet<Type> derivedTypes = new HashSet<Type>();

    public IEnumerable<Type> DerivedTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return derivedTypes.ToArray(); 
        }
        set
        {
            derivedTypes.Clear();
            if (value != null)
                derivedTypes.UnionWith(value);
        }
    }

    JsonObjectContract FindContract(JObject obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<JsonObjectContract> bestContracts = new List<JsonObjectContract>();
        foreach (var type in derivedTypes)
        {
            if (type.IsAbstract)
                continue;
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
            if (contract == null)
                continue;
            if (obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).Where(n => n != "$type").Any(n => contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(n) == null))
                continue;
            if (bestContracts.Count == 0 || bestContracts[0].Properties.Count > contract.Properties.Count)
            {
                bestContracts.Clear();
                bestContracts.Add(contract);
            }
            else if (contract.Properties.Count == bestContracts[0].Properties.Count)
            {
                bestContracts.Add(contract);
            }
        }
        return bestContracts.Single();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(T);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader); // Throws an exception if the current token is not an object.
        if (obj["$type"] != null && serializer.TypeNameHandling != TypeNameHandling.None)
        {
            // Prevent infinite recursion when using an explicit converter in the list.
            var removed = serializer.Converters.Remove(this);
            try
            {
                // Kludge to prevent infinite recursion when using JsonConverterAttribute on the type: deserialize to object.
                return obj.ToObject(typeof(object), serializer);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (removed)
                    serializer.Converters.Add(this);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var contract = FindContract(obj, serializer);
            if (contract == null)
                throw new JsonSerializationException("no contract found for " + obj.ToString());
            if (existingValue == null || !contract.UnderlyingType.IsAssignableFrom(existingValue.GetType()))
                existingValue = contract.DefaultCreator();
            using (var sr = obj.CreateReader())
            {
                serializer.Populate(sr, existingValue);
            }
            return existingValue;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh man, thank you so much!! I copied your Code to VS and it works out of the box (i just had to replace the dummy classes with my real model-classes). But why is it so complicated to achive this behaviour? why do I have to create such a (nice) JsonConverter to convert an interface?

Comment: i couldn't edit my comment...first I want to thank you for your quick and almost perfect answer. It works perfect when the client-data doesn't include the $type-property. but when it includes the $type-property this  bestContracts.Single(); throws an exception because it has no elements. for every type in the loop it runs in this case if (obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).Any(n => contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(n) == null)) continue; do you know how to tell him that the $type-property should be ignored?

Comment: @TobiasKoller - it's a little complicated because I wrote it to be general.  It would look simpler if hardcoded.  If the `$type` property is present then you shouldn't need any converter, Json.NET will create the correct type -- assuming you have set `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` **in both the client and server settings**.

Comment: @TobiasKoller - in other words, I'd suggest using one solution or the other, but not both.  Combining them makes both more complicated.

Comment: the problem I have is that my client is an angular-web-app and I guess there is no support for TypeNameHandling (I will check if there is). sorry but which two solutions do you mean? JsonConverter or TypeNameHandling.Auto?

Comment: one more question: how can I "not use" the JsonConverter if the $type-property is set? should I check this inside the JsonConverter or are there other ways?

Comment: @TobiasKoller - falling back to the default behavior once you've entered the converter is not so easy to do, the converter just gets invoked again recursively causing a stack overflow so some kludge is required.  That's why I suggest not implementing both solutions.

Comment: ok i disabled TypeNameHandling.Auto and now it works... I really appreciate your help for that problem. you saved me days of trying. I was trying and searching google for 2 days without luck. thank you!!

Comment: @TobiasKoller - OK, I enhanced it to check for `$type`.  As you can see it's more complex.

Comment: maybe you should add this return (bestContracts.Count()>0)? bestContracts.Single() : null; because this threw me once an exception. But anyway - very nice code. thanks again