# How to parse Json array of derived types?

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, azure-ad-graph-api

Here's the JSON response that I got from web service:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/00c6cd14-eaee-4d02-9807-59bcd4f98847/$metadata#domainDnsRecords",
    "value": [{
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.DomainDnsTxtRecord",
        "dnsRecordId": "aceff52c-06a5-447f-ac5f-256ad243cc5c",
        "isOptional": false,
        "label": "aro3652698.applabdnstest1.com",
        "recordType": "Txt",
        "supportedService": "Email",
        "ttl": 3600,
        "text": "MS=ms14815229"
    },
    {
        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.DomainDnsMxRecord",
        "dnsRecordId": "5fbde38c-0865-497f-82b1-126f596bcee9",
        "isOptional": false,
        "label": "aro3652698.applabdnstest1.com",
        "recordType": "Mx",
        "supportedService": "Email",
        "ttl": 3600,
        "mailExchange": "ms14815229.msv1.invalid",
        "preference": 32767
    }]
}
```

Elements in the array under "value" token are of different derived type.
There's `DomainDnsRecord` abstract base class, and classes that inherit from base are `DomainDnsTxtRecord` and `DomainDnsMxRecord`.
In the given JSON array (but not always!), first element is of `DomainDnsTxtRecord` and the second one is of `DomainDnsMxRecord` type.

The field that contains information about what type the given element is, is: "recordType".

What is the easiest, most convenient way to deserialize this JSON array into a list of base classes, e.g. `List<DomainDnsRecord>` (using Newtonsoft for example)?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752) or [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528648) or [JsonConverter with Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321698).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528648/json-net-serialization-of-type-with-polymorphic-child-object)

Comment: Note to readers: please use the Microsoft Graph API instead of the deprecated Azure AD Graph API.