# Deserialization of JSON from previous data model with Custom Converters fails when deserializing collections of Interfaces

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am responsible for maintaining a game system where users persist JSON serialized POCOs in a local cache to preserve state of, e.g., a `Character`.

The newest version of the code has changed the data model of these serialized objects.  In particular, a new interface was created.  This is creating issues when deserializing old copies of characters into the new code.  I am attempting to resolve these with custom converters, but I'm running into trouble.

old, serialized version:

```
public class Character{
  public Skill Parent {get;set;}
  public Dictionary<string,Skill} Skills {get;set;}
}

public class Skill {
//normal stuff here.
}
```

new version:

```
public class Character{
  [JsonProperty, JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<Dictionary<string,Skill>>))]
  public Dictionary<string,ISkill} Skills {get;set;}
}

public class Skill:ISkill {
//normal stuff here.
}

public interface ISkill{
//stuff that all skill-like things have here
}
```

I have further defined a custom converter class (having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780888/casting-interfaces-for-deserialization-in-json-net#) and [this](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/08/30/deserializing-interface-properties-using-json-net/),

but i'm still running into trouble deserializing collections.

```
public class Extensions 
{

//a lot of serializer extensions here including the Deserialize method
 private static readonly CustomSerializationBinder Binder = new CustomSerializationBinder();
        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
            Binder = Binder,
        };
}


 public class CustomSerializationBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder
    {


        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {

             return base.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);


        }
    }

    public class ConcreteTypeConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer,value); // serialization isnt't the problem.
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (typeof (T)==typeof(Dictionary<string,Skill>))
            {
                var retVal = new object();
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));  //crashes here
                    retVal = new List<T>() { instance };
                    return retVal;
                }
            }

            return serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true; // kind of a hack 
        }
    }
```

So i have an **old** `Dictionary<string,Skill>` and I can't cast that to `Dictionary<string,ISkill>` in any code-path that I can see.   How should I resolve this?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321698/jsonconverter-with-interface.  This gives a generic converter that will determine which concrete `Skill` class to deserialize for an `ISkill` interface by using `$type` if present, or if not, choosing the best property match.

Comment: I'll have a look.  I'm already using `$type` to solve some problems (at the expense of bloat), so maybe this is a good way forward.  

The problem i'm worried about is that the stale JSON is going to have a `$type` that's `Skill`, not `ISkill` -- and also, how to handle a `$type` that's `Dictionary<string,Skill>`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your problem.  Does your legacy JSON (from before the `Skill` to `ISkill` refactoring) contain `$type` information for the dictionary itself?

Comment: Yes.  legacy JSON would look like `$type: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[[System.String, mscorlib],[DataModel.Skill, PROJECT_NAME]]"` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your legacy JSON already contains type information for all objects including dictionary objects, what you need to do is to *strip* the type information for dictionaries and allow the deserialized dictionary type to be controlled by the code, not the JSON.

The following converter should do the job:

```
public class IgnoreDictionaryTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes().Count() == 1;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        existingValue = existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        obj.Remove("$type");
        using (var subReader = obj.CreateReader())
        {
            serializer.Populate(subReader, existingValue);
        }
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return all interfaces implemented by the incoming type as well as the type itself if it is an interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type[]> GetDictionaryKeyValueTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could add it in settings, or apply it to the dictionary property in question:

```
public class Character
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IgnoreDictionaryTypeConverter))]
    public IDictionary<string, ISkill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

For the future, you might also want disable emitting of type information for dictionaries, since dictionaries are collections, and collection types are better specified by the code, not the JSON:

```
public class Character
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IgnoreDictionaryTypeConverter))]
    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]
    public IDictionary<string, ISkill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This, with a custom SerializationBinder, did the trick.  thanks!