# Json.NET custom serialization with JsonConverter - how to get the "default" behavior

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JsonConverter for my class DataType. 
I would like to do some special handling when plain string used in Json as the value of a property of type DataType. In the case where the value is a "full" object, I would like to do the "normal" deserialization.

Here is my attempt

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.Value != null && reader.ValueType == typeof (string))
    {
        return someSpecialDataTypeInstance;
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        DataType dataType = serializer.Deserialize<DataType>(reader);
        return dataType;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new JsonSerializationException();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, because this line: 
DataType dataType = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
causes infinite recursion.

Could this be done somehow easily? (without the need to manually go property-by-property)

Comment: You skip some steps when you`re trying to deserialize . Take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One easy way to do it is to allocate an instance of your class then use [`JsonSerializer.Populate(JsonReader, Object)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm).  This is the way it is done in the standard [`CustomCreationConverter<T>`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/CustomCreationConverter.cs):

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.Value != null && reader.ValueType == typeof(string))
    {
        return someSpecialDataTypeInstance;
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        existingValue = existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator();
        serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
        return existingValue;
    }
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new JsonSerializationException();
    }
}
```

Limitations:

- This does not handle situations when [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_TypeNameHandling.htm) has been enabled and a `"$type"` property is present specifying a polymorphic subtype.

  In this case you'll need to do some of the tricks use by  `JsonDerivedTypeConverer<T>` in *[JsonConverter with Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322680/3744182)*.
- The type to be deserialized must have a [parameterless constructor](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_DefaultCreator.htm) accessible to Json.NET.  If not, and `existingValue` is null, it will be necessary to construct it manually, via `new DataType(arg1, arg2, ...)`.
- Reference preservation via [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm) is not supported.

  For one approach to handle this situation see *[How can I choose what type to deserialize at runtime based on the structure of the json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57814077/3744182)*.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5rKYyH).

Comment: The DefaultConvert() call throws NRE at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue). I replaced it with direct constructor call.... apart from that, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @j_maly - i'm having the same issue, but I can't figure out what the solution is based on your comment.  Can you post the modifications you made to this answer?

Comment: @dbc - Thank you for posting that fiddle.  It seems you are still calling DefaultCreator().  Like j_maly, I'm getting a NullReferenceException on DefaultCreator().  j_maly said "I replaced it with direct constructor call", but I couldn't interpret what he/she meant by that.  I was looking for the replacement/fix to solve the NullReferenceException issue.

Comment: @SFun28 - does your type have a public parameterless constructor?  If not that might be the problem.  If your type only has a single constructor, and that constructor is parameterized, then `DefaultCreator()` won't work.  Instead you'll have to construct your type manually by calling `new MyType(arg1, arg2, ... )`.

Comment: @dbc - my type does not have a public parameterless constructor.  I do have a customized contract resolver.  I also know that if my JsonConverter return false for CanConvert, that json.net is able to deserialize the type using the customized contract resolver.  Does that open up any options?

Comment: @SFun28 - Something should be possible, but your situation sounds different enough from the one in this question that I'd need to see a [mcve].  Maybe you could ask another question?

Comment: @dbc - agreed.  I did post a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913277/how-to-get-readjson-to-return-default-behavior-as-if-canconvert-returned-fal   but I should probably include some real code in there, just need to take the time to trim-down my implementation to the essentials needed to debug the issue.

Comment: @SFun28 - Just checked your new question, I agree a full [mcve] with real would make an answer more likely.