# JsonConverter where the property is composed of fields on its parent

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a situation where an API has multiple array-like objects as individual properties on a object.  For example:

```json
"parent": {
    id: 4,
    /*... other fields ...*/
    "prop_1": "A",
    "prop_2": "B",
    /*... other "props" ...*/
    "prop_24": "W"
}
```

I want the resulting model in C# to not repeat that same structure and have prop_X deserialized as a List and serialized back to that mess.

```cs
class Parent {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    /*... other properties ...*/
    public List<string> Props { get; set; }
}
```

I tried added `JsonConverter` attribute to the `Props` property, but I couldn't figure out how to get the props I needed on the parent.  I could add a converter to the parent object, but for two reasons it causes a problem.

1. Most of the fields map to simple properties and I don't want to have to write the code to manually deserialize and serialize all of them.
2. The convention of "prop_xx" fields appears in multiple objects and I'd hate to write JsonConverters for each object.

My idea was to have all the objects implement an interface, `IHasProps`, and write an `IHasPropsJsonConverter`.   The converter would try to use as much as the built in functionality to read and write props, except when encountering an attribute on a type that indicates its a prop object when write, and a field that matches the pattern `^prop\d+$` when reading.

This seems like *overkill*.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach of using a converter should work but is a little tricky to do in a generic fashion without getting a stack overflow exception.  For writing, see [Generic method of modifying JSON before being returned to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532466/generic-method-of-modifying-json-before-being-returned-to-client) for one way of doing it.  For reading, you can load into a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), populate the regular properties along the lines of [Json.NET custom serialization with JsonConverter - how to get the “default” behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586987/json-net-custom-serialization-with-jsonconverter-how-to-get-the-default-beha) then identify and parse the `"prop_XXX"` properties.  Note that these solutions don't play well with [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) or [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm).

However, a simpler approach may be to make use of [`[JsonExtensionData]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm) to temporarily store your variable set of properties in a `IDictionary<string, JToken>` during the serialization process and then add them to the `List<string> Props` when serialization is complete.  This can be done using [serialization callbacks](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm):

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent() { this.Props = new List<string>(); }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<string> Props { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    JObject extensionData; // JObject implements IDictionary<string, JToken> and preserves document order.

    [OnSerializing]
    void OnSerializing(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        VariablePropertyListExtensions.OnSerializing(Props, ref extensionData, false);
    }

    [OnSerialized]
    void OnSerialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        VariablePropertyListExtensions.OnSerialized(Props, ref extensionData, false);
    }

    [OnDeserializing]
    void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        VariablePropertyListExtensions.OnDeserializing(Props, ref extensionData, false);
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        if (Props == null)
            Props = new List<string>();
        VariablePropertyListExtensions.OnDeserialized(Props, ref extensionData, false);
    }
}

public static class VariablePropertyListExtensions
{
    public const string Prefix = "prop_";

    readonly static Regex regex;

    static VariablePropertyListExtensions()
    {
        regex = new Regex("^" + Prefix + @"\d+" + "$", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled); // Add  | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase if required
    }

    public static void OnSerializing<TDictionary>(IList<string> props, ref TDictionary extensionData, bool keepUnknownProperties) where TDictionary : class, IDictionary<string, JToken>, new()
    {
        Debug.Assert(keepUnknownProperties || (extensionData == null || extensionData.Count == 0));

        // Add the prop_ properties.
        if (props == null || props.Count < 1)
            return;
        extensionData = extensionData ?? new TDictionary();
        for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            extensionData.Add(Prefix + (i + 1).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), (JValue)props[i]);
    }

    internal static void OnSerialized<TDictionary>(IList<string> props, ref TDictionary extensionData, bool keepUnknownProperties) where TDictionary : class, IDictionary<string, JToken>, new()
    {
        // Remove the prop_ properties.
        if (extensionData == null)
            return;
        foreach (var name in extensionData.Keys.Where(k => regex.IsMatch(k)).ToList())
            extensionData.Remove(name);
        // null out extension data if no longer needed
        if (!keepUnknownProperties || extensionData.Count == 0)
            extensionData = null;
    }

    internal static void OnDeserializing<TDictionary>(IList<string> props, ref TDictionary extensionData, bool keepUnknownProperties) where TDictionary : class, IDictionary<string, JToken>, new()
    {
        Debug.Assert(keepUnknownProperties || (extensionData == null || extensionData.Count == 0));
    }

    internal static void OnDeserialized<TDictionary>(IList<string> props, ref TDictionary extensionData, bool keepUnknownProperties) where TDictionary : class, IDictionary<string, JToken>, new()
    {
        props.Clear();
        if (extensionData == null)
            return;
        foreach (var item in extensionData.Where(i => regex.IsMatch(i.Key)).ToList())
        {
            props.Add(item.Value.ToObject<string>());
            extensionData.Remove(item.Key);
        }
        // null out extension data if no longer needed
        if (!keepUnknownProperties || extensionData.Count == 0)
            extensionData = null;
    }
}
```

Here I have moved the logic for populating and deserializing the extension data dictionary to a helper class for reuse in multiple classes.  Note that I am adding the `"prop_XXX"` properties to the properties list in document order.  Since [the standard](http://www.json.org/) states that a JSON object is an *unordered* set of key/value pairs, for added robustness you might want to sort them by their `XXX` index.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GKW0Db).

Comment: A few things you might want to consider changing in your code:
 * `(JValue)props[i]` produced a run time error, I changed to `new JValue(props[i])`
 * Get rid of `OnDeserializing` since that does nothing.
 * Get rid of `IList<string> props` parameter from `OnSerialized`

Comment: **Great answer!**  I moved the regex and prefix into the methods so I can use this for multiple collections.  It even works when I have multiple collections in the same class, which was part of my use case but I didn't mention because I didn't want to muddy the question.  I also pass a collection of `KeyValuePair` to `OnSerializing` and a setting action to `OnDeserializing`.  This allowed for a lot more flexible implementation including handling the property values coming in out of order.

Comment: @DanielGimenez - thanks for the feedback.  I'm not sure why `(JValue)props[i]` fails since it works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GKW0Db).  The explicit cast is on [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Implicit_29.htm) though so maybe that's a problem in your environment.  You *might* want to check for pre-existing `"prop_XXX"` tokens in `OnDeserializing` which is why I left it in.  It could be removed though.  Either way all your changes sound good.

Comment: The reason why `(JValue)props[i]` didn't work for me is that I had changed the props value type from `string` to `object`.