# Deserialize a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, json.net

I have a generic type `Container<IContentType>` where interface `IContentType` can be one of four concrete `ContentX` types.

I serialize and everything is fine.

When deserializing using Newtonsoft I use custom type converters and `var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container<ContentA>>(json, settings)` works. The debugger shows I have an `Container<ContentA>` object.

My plan was when deserializing to attempt a deserialization for each of the four possible `ContentX` types and catch an exception silently until I "guess" the right one.

However, if I do this within a method like so:

```
public static Container<IContentType> Deserialize(jsonfile)
{
    ...
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container<ContentA>>(json, settings)
    return model;
}
```

I get "Cannot implicitly convert `Container<ContentA>` to `Container<IContentType>`". `ContentA` implements `IContentType`.

Is there a way I can create a cast operator, conversion, dynamic or make the implicit conversion work?

Comment: Why not just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container<ContentA>>(json, settings) as Container<IContentType>`?

Comment: You've run into a variance issue. For example, you can't cast `List<String>` to `List<Object>`, even though `string` is a subclass of `object`, because then the `List<Object>` reference would have a method `Add(Object)`, which wouldn't be valid for the actual `List<String>` that the reference "points" to.

Comment: You will need to create a custom `JsonConverter` for `IContentType` that infers the correct concrete type along the lines of [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182) or [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) or [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182).  Then you can just deserialize to `Container<IContentType>`.

Comment: This is covariance in action.  I think if you change the signature of the generic class `Container<T>` accordingly you'll be okay.

Comment: @dbc I am using the techniques you point to but you may have discovered an error in my implementation. During type resolution in the JsonConverter I am resolving to a Container<ContentA> and populating Container with those types. I will try instead to resolve to Conatiner<IContentType> but still populate with ContentA's...

Comment: @dbc If you'd like to post this answer I'll mark it as the solution. As I said I was using the methods in the links you provided but it prompted me to check my implementation which was wrong. During type resolution I was creating and instance of Container<ContentA> instead of Container<IContentType>. Once I changed that and added an IContentType converter to pass into Newtonsoft as a Converter, everything worked.

Comment: @user1200984 - OK, done.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to deserialize as a `Container<ContentX>` for concrete type(s) `X`, you should deserialize as a `Container<IContentType>` using a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that pre-load the JSON into a `JToken` and infers the concrete type along the lines of [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182) or [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) or [Json.Net Serialization of Type with Polymorphic Child Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29528648/3744182).

Thus your converter would look something like:

```
public class ContentConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(IContentType);
    }

    Type GetConcreteType(JObject obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetValue(nameof(ContentA.SomePropertyOfContentA), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != null)
            return typeof(ContentA);
        // Add other tests for other content types.
        // Return a default type or throw an exception if a unique type cannot be found.
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Cannot determine concrete type for IContentType");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var concreteType = GetConcreteType(obj);
        return obj.ToObject(concreteType, serializer);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And your call to `JsonConvert` would look like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ContentConverter() },
};
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container<IContentType>>(json, settings);
```

Finally, you might be able to choose the type *entirely automatically* using

```
new JsonDerivedTypeConverer<IContentType>(typeof(ContentA), typeof(ContentB), typeof(ContentC), typeof(ContentD))
```

Where `JsonDerivedTypeConverer<T>` is taken from [JsonConverter with Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322680/3744182).