# Json Array to Custom Object Mapping in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have this JSON Array as input.

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Test1",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Address": "London, GB",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Test3",
        "LastName": "Test4",
        "Address": "NewYork, US",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "ContactNumber",
        "Value": "01234 123 123"
    }
]
```

I want to build a JSON Object like this in C#

```
[
    "pages":{
        "FirstName": "Test1",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Address": "London, GB",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Test3",
        "LastName": "Test4",
        "Address": "NewYork, US",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
  "labels": {
        "DisplayName": "ContactNumber",
        "Value": "01234 123 123"
  }
}
]
```

I've created a Model with above output properties but they are not getting mapped when I deserialize the object into that Model. All values are returning null.

```
var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Config>>(serializedData);
```

the response I receive when I check is

```
[
    {
        "pages": null,
        "labels": null
    },
    {
        "pages": null,
        "labels": null
    }
]
```

Can anyone help me build the **Custom Model** for this format I want in **C#**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your desired JSON is invalid.  If you upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ you will get `Error: Parse error on line 7: Expecting 'STRING', got '{'`.  Should the values of `"pages"` and `"labels"` be arrays?

Comment: *I've created a Model with above properties but they are not getting mapped when I deserialize the object into that Model.* -- can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: try visual studio menu and create class from your json using it ...you might be facing problem because its not deserialize json string to your structure

Comment: I want to build a JSON Array like this
[{
 "Pages": { properties here},
 "Labels": { properties here }
}]

Comment: its better you provide full json string that you are inputing to function for conversion to object ...

Comment: serializedData value of this

Comment: @EKD : check my code below its working code , done code based on json string you provided before ...if string is different than please update same in your question

Comment: @EKD - things working for me for array of json also please check that also...and i suggest you check structure you are passing if below code update dont work for you,, for input i passed its working for me

Comment: @PranayRana I've updated the question. Apologies for misleading earlier with wrong input. I've updated the question.

Comment: @EKD - hi updated my answer , have a look your json structure is not valid one , also please accept / upvote answer if it works for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a polymorphic JSON array containing a variety of types of objects, distinguishable by the presence of specific properties (`"DisplayName"` vs `"FirstName"`, e.g.).  What you would like to do is to deserialize that into a c# model in which each possible array item gets added to a collection-valued property of your model, where the collection property is chosen to have the correct item type.

This can be accomplished by using a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).  Since the problem statement is generic I'm going to make the converter be generic.  A hardcoded converter would require less code.

First, define your desired model as follows:

```
public class Page
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

public class Label
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Page> pages { get; set; }
    public List<Label> labels { get; set; }
}
```

Next define the following converter:

```
public class PolymorphicArrayToObjectConverter<TObject> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(TObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    static JsonObjectContract FindContract(JObject obj, IEnumerable<Type> derivedTypes, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<JsonObjectContract> bestContracts = new List<JsonObjectContract>();
        foreach (var type in derivedTypes)
        {
            if (type.IsAbstract)
                continue;
            var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(type) as JsonObjectContract;
            if (contract == null)
                continue;
            if (obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).Any(n => contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(n) == null))
                continue;
            if (bestContracts.Count == 0 || bestContracts[0].Properties.Count > contract.Properties.Count)
            {
                bestContracts.Clear();
                bestContracts.Add(contract);
            }
            else if (contract.Properties.Count == bestContracts[0].Properties.Count)
            {
                bestContracts.Add(contract);
            }
        }
        return bestContracts.Single();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("JSON token is not an array at path: " + reader.Path);

        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        existingValue = existingValue ?? contract.DefaultCreator();

        var lookup = contract
            .Properties
            .Select(p => new { Property = p, PropertyContract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(p.PropertyType) as JsonArrayContract })
            .Where(i => i.PropertyContract != null)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.PropertyContract.CollectionItemType);
        var types = lookup.Select(i => i.Key).ToList();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Comment:
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    return existingValue;
                default:
                    {
                        var itemObj = JObject.Load(reader);
                        var itemContract = FindContract(itemObj, types, serializer);
                        if (itemContract == null)
                            continue;
                        var item = serializer.Deserialize(itemObj.CreateReader(), itemContract.UnderlyingType);
                        var propertyData = lookup[itemContract.UnderlyingType];
                        var collection = propertyData.Property.ValueProvider.GetValue(existingValue);
                        if (collection == null)
                        {
                            collection = propertyData.PropertyContract.DefaultCreator();
                            propertyData.Property.ValueProvider.SetValue(existingValue, collection);
                        }
                        collection.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(collection, new [] { item });
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Should not come here.
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unclosed array at path: " + reader.Path);
    }
}
```

Then, deserialize and re-serialize your `RootObject` collection as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new PolymorphicArrayToObjectConverter<RootObject>() },
};
var root = new List<RootObject> { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString, settings) };

var outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
```

As a result, the following JSON will be generated:

```
[
  {
    "pages": [
      {
        "FirstName": "Test1",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Address": "London, GB",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
      },
      {
        "FirstName": "Test3",
        "LastName": "Test4",
        "Address": "NewYork, US",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
      }
    ],
    "labels": [
      {
        "DisplayName": "ContactNumber",
        "Value": "01234 123 123"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HaduYM).

Note - code to automatically infer the array item type was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322680/3744182).

Comment: Works like a charm!
Thanks dbc.

This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you json is not valid json structure for parsing , this not valid at all(check what is wrong with it here : https://jsonlint.com/)

**not valid json string given by you**

```
[
    "pages":{
        "FirstName": "Test1",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Address": "London, GB",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Test3",
        "LastName": "Test4",
        "Address": "NewYork, US",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
  "labels": {
        "DisplayName": "ContactNumber",
        "Value": "01234 123 123"
  }
}
]
```

However I fixed json you given

**Fixed and working json**

```
[{
    "pages": [{
            "FirstName": "Test1",
            "LastName": "Test2",
            "Address": "London, GB",
            "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
        },
        {
            "FirstName": "Test3",
            "LastName": "Test4",
            "Address": "NewYork, US",
            "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
        }
    ],
    "labels": {
        "DisplayName": "ContactNumber",
        "Value": "01234 123 123"
    }
}]
```

After applying fix json , your C# object is

```
public class Page
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}

public class Labels
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Page> pages { get; set; }
    public Labels labels { get; set; }
}
```

and I tried this with my fixed json and its working fine.

**End of Edit**

---

Below code is working fine for me with the class structure i provided you in below

for list

```
var jsonString = "[{ \"pages\": {\"id\": 12345, \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"number\": \"123\", \"test\": "+
 "\"John\" }, \"labels\": { \"test\": \"test1\", \"test2\": \"test2\" } }," +
                            "{ \"pages\": {\"id\": 12345, \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"number\": \"123\", \"test\": "+
 "\"John\" }, \"labels\": { \"test\": \"test1\", \"test2\": \"test2\" } }]";

var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonString);
```

With single object as input

```
var jsonString = "{ \"pages\": {\"id\": 12345, \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"number\": \"123\", \"test\": "+
 "\"John\" }, \"labels\": { \"test\": \"test1\", \"test2\": \"test2\" } }";

 var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

based on input

```
{ "pages": { "id": 12345, "name": "John Doe", "number": "123", "test": 
 "John" }, "labels": { "test": "test1", "test2": "test2" } }
```

below is generated classes

```
public class Pages
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string test { get; set; }
}

public class Labels
{
    public string test { get; set; }
    public string test2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Pages pages { get; set; }
    public Labels labels { get; set; }
}
```

---

If you have Json with you than you can generate C# class using visual studio itself.

In visual studio Find "Paste Sepcial" menu. i.e. copy you json string and click on Paste special , it will generate C# class for you.

you can follow my post : [Generate Class From JSON or XML in Visual Studio](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/07/introduction-below-article-is-on-one-of.html)

[image]

or use online website like : [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: My input is 
[
    {
        "FirstName": "Test1",
        "LastName": "Test2",
        "Address": "London, GB",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "Test3",
        "LastName": "Test4",
        "Address": "NewYork, US",
        "Error": "Something's gone wrong"
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "ContactNumber",
        "Value": "01234 123 123"
    }
]

I've generated the class using Paste JSON as classes. And still I'm getting response as null

The input I'm providing is a JSON Array. I wnt it with custom defined in JSON

Comment: @EKD please provide your code of C# for doing this operation

Comment: var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Config>>(serializedData);

Output
[
    {        
        "pages": null,
        "labels": null
    },
    {        
        "pages": null,
        "labels": null
    }
]

Comment: @EKD - please provide your full json also .....i am trying things at my end

Comment: I've updated the question properly now @Pranay
Looking forward for your help.