# C# - Post a model with generic property (Web API)

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller

I have this situation:

```
public class Dto 
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public IType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Type1 : IType
{
   public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class Type2 : IType
{
   public int PropertyB { get; set; }
   public bool PropertyC { get; set; }
}

public class MyController : ApiController
{
   [HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult Post(Dto dto) 
   {
   }
}
```

How can I deserialize for the correct implementation of IType interface, depending on the value of the TypeId property?

I tried using JsonConverter (following this example: https://gist.github.com/teamaton/bba69cf95b9e6766f231), but I can only specify one concrete type:

```
public class Dto 
{
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<Type1>)]
    public IType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonConverter` is the correct way to go, however the `ConcreteTypeConverter` isn't for your case.

Assume you need to determine which concrete type to create at runtime based on `TypeId`, you will need a `JsonConverter` on `Dto` not on `Type` property.

Try this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DtoJsonConverter))]
public class Dto
{
    public IType Type { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
}

class DtoJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Dto);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // Load this to a JObject so that we can read TypeId
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var typeId = obj["TypeId"].Value<int>();

        // Figure out JSON covnerter for type property based on TypeId
        JsonConverter converter = null;
        switch (typeId)
        {
            // Assuming 1 means Type1
            case 1:
                converter = new CreateITypeJsonConverter(() => new Type1());
                break;
            case 2:
                converter = new CreateITypeJsonConverter(() => new Type2());
                break;
        }

        if (converter != null)
        {
            serializer.Converters.Add(converter);
        }

        try
        {
            // Now create Dto and populate the object.
            // This will call the JsonConverter we just added for Type property.
            var dto = new Dto();
            serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), dto);
            return dto;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (converter != null)
            {
                serializer.Converters.Remove(converter);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

class CreateITypeJsonConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IType>
{
    private readonly Func<IType> _factory;

    public CreateITypeJsonConverter(Func<IType> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public override IType Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return _factory();
    }
}
```

The `DtoJsonConverter` works out the concrete type of `IType` as per the value of `TypeId`, and use another `CreateITypeJsonConverter` to instantiate the concrete type, then populate the `Dto`.

It is also possible that you could move `TypeId` into `IType`, then use one of the methods in this question: [JsonConverter with Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321698/jsonconverter-with-interface)