# Deserialize a Json object with a Dictionary inside a list inside an object

Tags: json, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have a set of data inside a Json file that represents the GPD evolution for each country every year. I'm trying to extract this data inside a list where every year would be a dictionary inside the list.

This is a part of the Json I'm trying to work with :

```
{
    "Name": "GPD per capita",
    "Description": "Real GDP per capita in 2011US$, 2011 benchmark (suitable for cross-country growth comparisons)",
    "Suffix": "$",
    "Multiplier": "1",
    "Data": [
        {
            "year": "1",
            "Belgium": "1050",
            "Switzerland": "1050",
            "Egypt": "1225",
            "Spain": "973",
            "France": "1050",
            "Greece": "1400",
            "Iran (Islamic Republic of)": "1225",
            "Iraq": "1225",
            "Israel": "1225",
            "Italy": "1546",
            "Jordan": "1225",
            "Portugal": "1050",
            "Tunisia": "1225",
            "Turkey": "984"
        },
        {
            "year": "730",
            "Egypt": "1278",
            "Iraq": "1610",
            "Japan": "633"
        },
        ...
```

And this is the class where the Json file should be deserialized :

```
[Serializable]
public class Collection
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public string Suffix;
    public ulong Multiplier;

    public List<IDictionary<string, ulong>> Data;
}
```

When I do `Collection collection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Collection>(jsonFile.ToString());` all the attributes show on the console but not the *Data* list.

How can I deserialize such structure correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

`interface`s are not (De)Serializable since the Deserializer can not know as which final actual type it should Deserialize it.

Instead of an `IDictionary` simply rather use an actual `Dictionary`

```
public List<Dictionary<string, ulong> Data;
```

---

Alternatively you would need to add to the JSON the actual type in order to tell the Deserializer which type shall be used for the Deserialization.

See [How to automatically select a concrete type when deserializing an interface using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322680/7111561)